# Remote R process Dies

Tags: r, ssh, parallel-processing

I am running R on an Ubuntu machine and trying to utilize a remote Ubuntu machine for parallel processing. I can ssh to the remote machine.

```
hosts="remoteIPaddress"; cluster=makeCluster(hosts, type="PSOCK",user="myusername",master="mylocalIPaddress"); registerDoParallel(cluster); foreach(i=1:100,.combine="rbind") %dopar% i^2
```

The makeCluster command prompts me for my password and on the remote machine I can see an R process start when this is entered. This process immediately dies and when I run the foreach command, I get "Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from connection". Does anyone know what is going on?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] grDevices datasets  grid      parallel  utils     stats     graphics  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] quantmod_0.3-17              TTR_0.21-1                   Defaults_1.1-1               portfolio_0.4-5             
 [5] nlme_3.1-104                 lattice_0.20-6               PerformanceAnalytics_1.0.4.4 xts_0.8-6                   
 [9] zoo_1.7-8                    np_0.40-13                   cubature_1.1-1               doParallel_1.0.1            
[13] iterators_1.0.6              foreach_1.4.0                boot_1.3-5                  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 compiler_2.15.1 tools_2.15.1
```

Comment: The results of your `sessionInfo()` may be useful here.

Comment: Just posted sessionInfo() from the local machine.